# Google Sheets Script: Referencing a different sheet in setFormula()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script in Google Sheets that enters in a formula which references data from a cell in a different sheet. (Ex: ='Monthly Expenses'!A1).

I made variables for "name" and "cell", so the line of code looks like this:

```
cell.setFormula(name+"!A1");
```

It works when the sheet name is just one word, but when two or more words are added, the single quotes are obviously required, and I can't seem to add them to the setFormula and get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `"'" + name + "'!" + "A1"`

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
cell.setFormula("'" + name + "'!" + "A1");
```